# Multiple string method chained in single code

Tags: java, string

I  am  working  on this  bit  of  code

```
public class SimpleStringTest {
public static void main(String args[])
{
String ints="123456789";
System.out.println(ints.concat("0").substring(ints.indexOf("2"),ints.indexOf("0")));
}
```

As  per  as  my  knowledge  on  java  "When the multiple methods are chained on a single code statement, the methods execute from left to right" Then,  Why  is  this  bit  of  code  throwing  StringIndexOutOfBondsException?

Thanks  in  advance,
GPAR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `String`s are immutable.

By invoking `concat`, you are not modifying `ints`, you are creating a new `String`.

Therefore by the time you invoke `ints.indexOf("0")`, `ints` is still equal to its former value and the `indexOf` invocation returns `-1`, which in turn will be the outer bound of your `substring`.

Try a counter-example with a mutable `CharSequence` such as `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder ints = new StringBuilder("123456789");
System.out.println(ints.append("0").substring(ints.indexOf("2"),ints.indexOf("0")));
```

**Output**

```
23456789
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `ints.indexOf("0")` is applied on the original String `ints` (not the one you concatenate).

Since there is no "0" `indexOf("0")` returns -1 and which throws the exception.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
String ints="123456789";
int indexOne = ints.indexOf("2");
int indexTwo = ints.indexOf("0");
System.out.println(ints.concat("0").substring(indexOne, indexTwo));
```